# How can I track all of the webpages that have embedded a video online using the embed url?

Tags: search, reverse, web-crawler

How can I track all of the webpages that have embedded a video online using the embed url?

Are there any search engines that will crawl web pages for instances of an embed url link within source code.

Answer (score 0):

**On "How you can track the webpages":**

To find out in which webpages this url got embedded you would need to have a look at all of them. So doing this with your own resources (a script and your network connection for example) would most probably be too much to handle. 
(Unless you've got a really huge serverfarm at your hands.)

**On "Are there search engines for that":**

I doubt, that the big ones will give this kind of access o their data, but I don't know for sure.